# How to ignore @Transactional in JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to create a library (jar) and use JdbcTemplate in it to simplify working with Database. But that library will be used in other Spring applications. And by default @Transactional annonations in application will affect the methods in library (JdbcTemplate in library will be aware of that outer Transaction). So I need to create JdbcTemplate so that it will ignore outer transactions. Is that possible?

Comment: `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)`? Though generally speaking, you *should* be joining the external transaction context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Application transaction propagation level shouldn't effect your library transaction management, is this my understanding correct?

If Yes, you may have a look at `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED`, [ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED)

I believe you are going to design interface in your library which will expose public methods used by application, what if all interface method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` ? wouldn't it solve your problem.